# Mostrar a idade entre 20 e 30 em um array - javaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Gostaria de criar uma função o mais simples possível que receba um Array de objetos Pessoa (formato exemplo: `{name: "Alex",age: 24}` ) que retorne um novo *array* somente com os objetos Pessoa que possuem idade entre 20 e 30 anos.

Meu código é esse:

```
var pessoa = [{
        nome: 'Diego',
        age: 17,
    },
    {
        nome: 'Natalia',
        age: 12,
    },
    {
        nome: 'David',
        age: 27,
    },
    {
        nome: 'Daniel',
        age: 30,
    },
];

function idade(pessoa) {
    if (age => 20 && <= 30) {
        (a partir daqui nao sei como fazer)
    }    
}
```

Não sei se o código está certo, quero uma ajuda de como fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma é usar o [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) do javascript para filtrar somente as pessoas que entrarem no critério da idade:

```js
var pessoas = [{
    nome: 'Diego',
    age: 17,
  },
  {
    nome: 'Natalia',
    age: 12,
  },
  {
    nome: 'David',
    age: 27,
  },
  {
    nome: 'Daniel',
    age: 30,
  },
];

function idade(pessoas) {
  return pessoas.filter(pessoa => pessoa.age > 19 && pessoa.age < 31);
}

var novoArray = idade(pessoas);
console.log(novoArray);
```

Usando o `for` clássico:

```js
var pessoas = [{
    nome: 'Diego',
    age: 17,
  },
  {
    nome: 'Natalia',
    age: 12,
  },
  {
    nome: 'David',
    age: 27,
  },
  {
    nome: 'Daniel',
    age: 30,
  },
];

function idade(pessoas) {
  let novoArray = [];
  for (let i = 0 ; i < pessoas.length ; i++){
      if (pessoas[i].age > 19 && pessoas[i].age < 31)
         novoArray.push(pessoas[i]);
  }
  return novoArray;
}

var novoArray = idade(pessoas);
console.log(novoArray);
```

Comment: Só um detalhe que você está usando a função de flecha ("arrow function") que só é disponível começando com o ES6. Se não der para usar, volta pra `function() { return ...; }` dentro da callback passada pra `filter`.

Comment: Isso mesmo, bem comentado @nbkhope =]